# How to iterate over specific key in an object?

Tags: javascript

How would I write a function that takes two arguments (the array `responses` and a `string`), and for the `isEssayQuestion`s that are true, compares the `string` parameter to the `response` key value and returns `true` if they match anyone and `false` if it doesn't match any.

```js
const responses = [
  {
    question: 'What is the phase where chromosomes line up in mitosis?',
    response: 'Metaphase',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  },
  {
    question: 'What anatomical structure connects the stomach to the mouth?',
    response: 'Esophagus',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  },
  {
    question: 'What are lysosomes?',
    response: 'A lysosome is a membrane-bound organelle found in many animal cells. They are spherical vesicles that contain hydrolytic enzymes that can break down many kinds of biomolecules.',
    isCorrect: true,
    isEssayQuestion: true
  },
  {
    question: 'True or False: Prostaglandins can only constrict blood vessels.',
    response: 'True',
    isCorrect: false,
    isEssayQuestion: false
  }
];

// example
checkForPlagiarism(responses, 'spherical vesicles that contain hydrolytic enzymes'); //> true
checkForPlagiarism(responses, 'this string does not appear in the responses'); //> false

// my code
function checkForPlagiarism(test, answerKey) {
  for (let i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    let question = test[i];
    if (question.isEssayQuestion) {
      let response = question.response;
      return response.includes(answerKey);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `const checkResponses = (resps, checkStr) => resps.filter(r => r.isEssayQuestion).some(r => r.response.includes(checkStr))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is already returning the correct values (true if a match was found or false if no match has been found), just add a return false after the for loop if no match was found (with no isEssayQuestion: true).
Do a console.log() on the values returned by your function calls to check it out.

Examples:

console.log(checkForPlagiarism(responses, 'spherical vesicles that contain hydrolytic enzymes'))
console.log(checkForPlagiarism(responses, 'this string does not appear in the responses'))

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate over the object, as the given response is an array itself.

What you've done seems pretty fine to me except for `return` statement.
So add your return statement in the `if` of string match logic.

```
function checkForPlagiarism(test, answerKey) {
  for (let i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    let question = test[i];
    if (question.isEssayQuestion) {
      let response = question.response;
      if (response.includes(answerKey)) return true;
    }
  }
  return false
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I see when I returned `response.includes(answerKey)` it would just return true or false instead looping through the whole list of responses. Right?

Comment: Yes. your `return` condition wasn't the string match, but only `isEssayQuestion` flag